# Extracting PCA components with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am using [sklearn's PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) for dimensionality reduction on a large set of images. Once the PCA is fitted, I would like to see what the components look like.

One can do so by looking at the `components_` attribute. Not realizing that was available, I did something else instead:

```
each_component = np.eye(total_components)
component_im_array = pca.inverse_transform(each_component)

for i in range(num_components):
   component_im = component_im_array[i, :].reshape(height, width)
   # do something with component_im
```

In other words, I create an image in the PCA space that has all features but 1 set to 0. By inversely transforming them, I should then get the image in the original space which, once transformed, can be expressed solely with that PCA component.

The following image shows the results. On the left is the component calculated using my method. On the right is `pca.components_[i]` directly. Additionally, with my method, most images are very similar (but they *are* different) while by accessing the `components_` the images are very different as I would have expected

Is there a conceptual problem in my method? Clearly the components from `pca.components_[i]` are correct (or at least more correct) than the ones I'm getting. Thanks!

[image: left: calculated component, right: real component]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between grabbing the `components_` and doing an `inverse_transform` on the identity matrix is that the latter adds in the empirical mean of each feature. I.e.:

```
def inverse_transform(self, X):
    return np.dot(X, self.components_) + self.mean_
```

where `self.mean_` was estimated from the training set.

Comment: Bingo. I don't know why I didn't look at the source code myself earlier. Thanks! However, the mean is calculated as `self.mean_ = np.mean(X, axis=0)` in PCA._fit(X), where X is an array of `n_samples` rows and `n_features` columns, so the mean is the mean across the features, for each feature, so that's of course likely to dominate whatever contribution the component actually has, which is why all the images look almost the same. All explained, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Components and inverse transform are two different things. The inverse transform maps the components back to the original image space

```
#Create a PCA model with two principal components
pca = PCA(2)
pca.fit(data)
#Get the components from transforming the original data.
scores = pca.transform(data)
# Reconstruct from the 2 dimensional scores 
reconstruct = pca.inverse_transform(scores )
#The residual is the amount not explained by the first two components
residual=data-reconstruct
```

Thus you are inverse transforming the original data and not the components, and thus they are completely different. You almost never inverse_transform the orginal data. pca.components_ are the actual vectors representing the underlying axis used to project the data to the pca space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps we have a misunderstanding: I am not inverse transforming the original data, but a vector that's all zeros except for one position. In doing so I expect I'm inverse transforming an image `[0,0,...,0,1,0,...,0]` which must come from an original image that looked like the component