# Finding original variable names of the important attibutes in a FAMD PCA using Prince

Tags: python, pca

I'm using the package Prince to perform a FAMD on data that consists of mixed data (so both categorical and non-categorical).

My code is the following:

```
famd = prince.FAMD(n_components=10, n_iter=3, copy=True, check_input=True, engine='auto', random_state=42)
famd = famd.fit(df_pca)
```

Which gives as output

```
Explained inertia
[0.08057161 0.05946225 0.03875787 0.03203083 0.02978785 0.02868602
 0.02499968 0.02416245 0.02207422 0.02055546]
```

I have already tried `df = pd.DataFrame(pca.components_, columns=list(dfPca.columns))` as mentioned in [PCA on sklearn - how to interpret pca.components_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370795/pca-on-sklearn-how-to-interpret-pca-components) . Next to that I have attempted to implement the solution offered by user seralouk with some minor changes to make it fit the Prince FAMD.

```
n_pcs = len(inertia)
most_important = [inertia[i].argmax() for i in range(n_pcs)]
initial_feature_names = df_pca.columns
most_important_names = [initial_feature_names[most_important[i]] for i in range(n_pcs)]
dic = {'PC{}'.format(i): most_important_names[i] for i in range(n_pcs)}
pca_results = pd.DataFrame(dic.items())
```

However this does not appear to work for the Prince FAMD. Are there any ways to link the output of the FAMD to the original variable names?

Answer (score 0):

The link you cited is for a pca in sklearn. You are using a famd from another package now which is quite different altogether.

In the link cited, the solution by @seralouk basically goes through the eigenvector for each PC and takes out the column with highest absolute weight. Note this is **NOT** linking each component to the original column. This is finding the original column which contribute most to the PC.

You can do something like below, but I would suggest reading up on FAMD / PCA in [this book](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/practical-guide-to-principal-component-methods-in-r) to be sure of what you are actually extracting:

Below is a rough implementation to get the columns that contribute most to each component, using the V matrix. Using the example in [prince help page](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince#factor-analysis-of-mixed-data-famd):

```
import pandas as pd

X = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
    ['A', 'A', 'A', 2, 5, 7, 6, 3, 6, 7],
    ['A', 'A', 'A', 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3],
    ['B', 'A', 'B', 5, 2, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1],
    ['B', 'A', 'B', 7, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    ['B', 'B', 'B', 3, 5, 6, 5, 2, 6, 6],
    ['B', 'B', 'A', 3, 5, 4, 5, 1, 7, 5]
    ],
    columns=['E1 fruity', 'E1 woody', 'E1 coffee',
    'E2 red fruit', 'E2 roasted', 'E2 vanillin', 'E2 woody',
    'E3 fruity', 'E3 butter', 'E3 woody'],
    index=['Wine {}'.format(i+1) for i in range(6)]
    )

import prince
import numpy as np

n_pcs = 3
famd = prince.FAMD(n_components=n_pcs)
famd = famd.fit(X)

most_important = np.abs(famd.V_).argmax(axis=1)
initial_feature_names = X.columns
most_important_names = initial_feature_names[most_important]
dic = {'PC{}'.format(i+1): most_important_names[i] for i in range(n_pcs)}
pca_results = pd.DataFrame(dic.items())

     0             1
0  PC1     E1 coffee
1  PC2      E1 woody
2  PC3  E2 red fruit
```