# Add legend to scatter plot (PCA)

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, pca, biplot

I am a newbie with python and found this excellent PCA biplot suggestion ([Plot PCA loadings and loading in biplot in sklearn (like R's autoplot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216897/plot-pca-loadings-and-loading-in-biplot-in-sklearn-like-rs-autoplot)). Now I tried to add a legend to the plot for the different targets. But the command `plt.legend()` doesn't work.

Is there an easy way to do it?
As an example, the iris data with the biplot code from the link above.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
#In general a good idea is to scale the data
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
X=scaler.transform(X)    

pca = PCA()
x_new = pca.fit_transform(X)

def myplot(score,coeff,labels=None):
    xs = score[:,0]
    ys = score[:,1]
    n = coeff.shape[0]
    scalex = 1.0/(xs.max() - xs.min())
    scaley = 1.0/(ys.max() - ys.min())
    plt.scatter(xs * scalex,ys * scaley, c = y)
    for i in range(n):
        plt.arrow(0, 0, coeff[i,0], coeff[i,1],color = 'r',alpha = 0.5)
        if labels is None:
            plt.text(coeff[i,0]* 1.15, coeff[i,1] * 1.15, "Var"+str(i+1), color = 'g', ha = 'center', va = 'center')
        else:
            plt.text(coeff[i,0]* 1.15, coeff[i,1] * 1.15, labels[i], color = 'g', ha = 'center', va = 'center')
plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)
plt.xlabel("PC{}".format(1))
plt.ylabel("PC{}".format(2))
plt.grid()

#Call the function. Use only the 2 PCs.
myplot(x_new[:,0:2],np.transpose(pca.components_[0:2, :]))
plt.show()
```

Any suggestions for PCA biplots are welcome!
Also other codes, if the adding of the legend is easier in another way!

Comment: Did you read https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html?

Comment: yes, but I don't understand how I can add it to my existing code :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently proposed an easy way to add a legend to a scatter, see [GitHub PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/11127). This is still being discussed.

In the meantime you need to manually create your legend from the unique labels in `y`. For each of them you'd create a `Line2D` object with the same marker as is used in the scatter plot and supply them as argument to `plt.legend`.

```
scatter = plt.scatter(xs * scalex,ys * scaley, c = y)
labels = np.unique(y)
handles = [plt.Line2D([],[],marker="o", ls="", 
                      color=scatter.cmap(scatter.norm(yi))) for yi in labels]
plt.legend(handles, labels)
```

[image]

Comment: Might be useful to others: if you add `labels=["label_A", "label_B", "label_C"]` just before `plt.legend(handles, labels)`, you can change the labels that will show up in the box. Attempting to change them before the `handles` iteration messes with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [pca library](https://erdogant.github.io/pca). This will plot the explained variance, and create a biplot.

```
pip install pca

from pca import pca

# Initialize to reduce the data up to the number of componentes that explains 95% of the variance.
model = pca(n_components=0.95)

# Or reduce the data towards 2 PCs
model = pca(n_components=2)

# Load example dataset
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
X = pd.DataFrame(data=load_iris().data, columns=load_iris().feature_names, index=load_iris().target)

# Fit transform
results = model.fit_transform(X)

# Plot explained variance
fig, ax = model.plot()
```

[image: explained variance PCs]

```
# Scatter first 2 PCs
fig, ax = model.scatter()

# Make biplot with the number of features
fig, ax = model.biplot(n_feat=4)
```

[image: PCA biplot]

The results is a dict containing many statistics of the PCs, loadings etc