# How to add a legend to scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am doing an exercise for a Machine Learning course.
I appended to a matrix a dataset of images in form of arrays into datamatrix, then I standardized it and then computed the principal components.
Labels is an array containing for each image the label (that was the subdirectory containing it)
I need to visualize pairs of principal components, in this part the first two. The suggestion from the professor was to use the matplotli.scatter function, I found the seaborn.scatterplot function that seems better, but with none of the two I managed to put a legend with the labels names onto it.

```
pca = PCA()
X_t = pca.fit_transform(datamatrix)
X_r = pca.inverse_transform(X_t)

plt.figure(figsize=(25,5))

colours = ['r','g','b','p']
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
sns.scatterplot(X_t[:,0], X_t[:,1], hue=labels, palette=colours, legend='full')
plt.title('PC 1 and 2')
```

I am new to Python and to Machine Learnings libaries

Edit:
As suggested I tried modifying the cod:

```
data = {"x" : X_t[:,0], "y" : X_t[:,1], "label" : labels}
sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", hue="label", palette=colours, data=data, legend='full')
```

But I obtain the same result: I have the legend, but without the name of the labels
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6dii.jpg)

Comment: It is more useful to include the full code so the problem can be fixed more efficiently. This code for example does not run due to missing relevant imports.

Comment: I don't know what you have tried yet, but what about getting the axes with gca() and adding the legend there? Or just plt.legend(..)?
For more info on both, simply google.

Answer (score 0):

Before showing the plot add the legend using:

```
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn `scatterplot` will automatically create a legend as shown in the second example from [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html). It does however require to have the data in a dictionary-like structure, which is common for pandas dataframes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {"x" : np.random.rand(10),
        "y" : np.random.rand(10),
        "label" : np.random.choice(["Label 1", "Label 2"], size=10)}

sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", hue="label", data=data)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To achieve the same via matplotlib's `scatter` you would need to create the legend yourself, which is indeed a bit more cumbersome, but may be helpful for understanding.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {"x" : np.random.rand(10),
        "y" : np.random.rand(10),
        "label" : np.random.choice(["Label 1", "Label 2"], size=10)}

labels, inv = np.unique(data["label"], return_inverse=True)
scatter = plt.scatter(x="x", y="y", c = inv, data=data)

handles = [plt.Line2D([],[],marker="o", ls="", 
                      color=scatter.cmap(scatter.norm(yi))) for yi in np.unique(inv)]
plt.legend(handles, labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Also see [Add legend to scatter plot (PCA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654620/add-legend-to-scatter-plot-pca/50655866#50655866)