# Find out which features are in my components after PCA

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statistics, pca

I performed a PCA of my data. The data looks like the following:

```
df
Out[60]: 
        Drd1_exp1  Drd1_exp2  Drd1_exp3  ...  M7_pppp  M7_puuu  Brain_Region
0            -1.0       -1.0       -1.0  ...      0.0      0.0          BaGr

3            -1.0       -1.0       -1.0  ...      0.0      0.0          BaGr
4            -1.0       -1.0       -1.0  ...      0.0      0.0          BaGr
          ...        ...        ...  ...      ...      ...           ...
150475       -1.0       -1.0       -1.0  ...      0.0      0.0          BaGr
150478       -1.0       -1.0       -1.0  ...      0.0      0.0          BaGr
150479       -1.0       -1.0       -1.0  ...      0.0      0.0          BaGr
```

I know used every row until 'Brain Regions' as features. I also standardized them.
These features are different experiments, that give me information about a 3D image of a brain.
I'll show you my code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
x = df.loc[:, listend1].values
y= df.loc[:, 'Brain_Region'].values

x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
             , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])

finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, df[['Brain_Region']]], axis = 1)
```

I then plotted finalDF:

[image]

My question now is: **How can I find out, which features contribute to my Components? How can I find out, to interpret the data?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Feature/Variable importance after a PCA analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796024/feature-variable-importance-after-a-pca-analysis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pca.components_` (or `pca.components` depending on the sklearn version).
It has shape `(n_components, n_features)`, in your case `(2, n_features)` and represents the directions of maximum variance in the data, which reflects the magnitude of the corresponding values in the eigenvectors (higher magnitude - higher importance). You will have something like this:

```
[[0.522 0.26 0.58 0.56],
 [0.37 0.92 0.02 0.06]]
```

implying that for the first component (first row) the first, third and last features have an higher importance, while for the second component only the second feature is important.

Have a look to [sklern PCA attributes description](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) or to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50845697/6837288).

By the way, you can also use a [Random Forest Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) including the labels, and after the training you can explore the feature importance, e.g. this [post](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-inspection-plot-permutation-importance-py).