# Create a PCA plot in R with a PCA calculated in ArcGIS

Tags: r, arcgis, arcpy

A colleague of mine ran this PCA on 9 raster tif images in ArcGIS. We are trying to plot the resulting output into a biplot like style (example image below). Now I understand that I don't have individual points, but all I am really interested in is plotting the Eigen vectors.

I've tried coercing a dataframe of the eigen vectors into a list and using the stats::autoplot. My list was not in the right format with just the matrix of eigen vectors.

I am also open to using python to solve the issue since the PCA was calculated in arc.py.

[image]

Example data:

```
# Data file produced by Principal Components
#   Input raster(s):
#       Curve_Render.tif\Band_1
#       CurvePlanar_Render.tif\Band_1
#       CurveProfile_Render.tif\Band_1
#       Mean_Render.tif\Band_1
#       Render.tif\Band_1
#       Rugosity_Render.tif\Band_1
#       Slope_Render.tif\Band_1
#       SlopeofSlope_Render.tif\Band_1
#       StandardDev_Render.tif\Band_1
#   The number of components = 9



#                    COVARIANCE MATRIX

#    Layer             1             2             3             4             5             6             7             8             9
#  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1            3.27720       2.15133      -3.24609       0.08826       0.88220       0.26019       0.12200      -1.62747       0.17326
    2            2.15133       1.82395      -1.57062      -0.00032       0.52187       0.50452       0.99731       1.50169       0.95937
    3           -3.24609      -1.57062       3.97780      -0.16671      -0.95173       0.19645       1.12744       5.10968       0.97922
    4            0.08826      -0.00032      -0.16671    1851.41857    1842.77634      -2.58266     -21.97807    -163.53637     -26.21676
    5            0.88220       0.52187      -0.95173    1842.77634    1834.38053      -2.49154     -21.82099    -163.24386     -26.03641
    6            0.26019       0.50452       0.19645      -2.58266      -2.49154       3.76810       9.07100      20.39137       8.70026
    7            0.12200       0.99731       1.12744     -21.97807     -21.82099       9.07100      37.11085      97.36823      31.06467
    8           -1.62747       1.50169       5.10968    -163.53637    -163.24386      20.39137      97.36823     834.80181      90.59780
    9            0.17326       0.95937       0.97922     -26.21676     -26.03641       8.70026      31.06467      90.59780      28.12504
#  ==========================================================================


#                    CORRELATION MATRIX

#    Layer             1             2             3             4             5             6             7             8             9
#  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1       1.000000e+00  8.799332e-01 -8.990588e-01  1.133104e-03  1.137808e-02  7.404066e-02  1.106228e-02 -3.111503e-02  1.804687e-02
    2       8.799332e-01  1.000000e+00 -5.831008e-01 -5.447399e-06  9.022221e-03  1.924460e-01  1.212197e-01  3.848413e-02  1.339465e-01
    3      -8.990588e-01 -5.831008e-01  1.000000e+00 -1.942591e-03 -1.114166e-02  5.074252e-02  9.279446e-02  8.867083e-02  9.257942e-02
    4       1.133104e-03 -5.447399e-06 -1.942591e-03  1.000000e+00  9.999438e-01 -3.092095e-02 -8.384687e-02 -1.315438e-01 -1.148894e-01
    5       1.137808e-02  9.022221e-03 -1.114166e-02  9.999438e-01  1.000000e+00 -2.996828e-02 -8.363330e-02 -1.319169e-01 -1.146278e-01
    6       7.404066e-02  1.924460e-01  5.074252e-02 -3.092095e-02 -2.996828e-02  1.000000e+00  7.670852e-01  3.635745e-01  8.451314e-01
    7       1.106228e-02  1.212197e-01  9.279446e-02 -8.384687e-02 -8.363330e-02  7.670852e-01  1.000000e+00  5.531910e-01  9.615450e-01
    8      -3.111503e-02  3.848413e-02  8.867083e-02 -1.315438e-01 -1.319169e-01  3.635745e-01  5.531910e-01  1.000000e+00  5.912612e-01
    9       1.804687e-02  1.339465e-01  9.257942e-02 -1.148894e-01 -1.146278e-01  8.451314e-01  9.615450e-01  5.912612e-01  1.000000e+00
#  ==========================================================================


#   The number of components = 9
#                    COVARIANCE MATRIX

#    Layer             1             2             3             4             5             6             7             8             9
#  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1            3.27720       2.15133      -3.24609       0.08826       0.88220       0.26019       0.12200      -1.62747       0.17326
    2            2.15133       1.82395      -1.57062      -0.00032       0.52187       0.50452       0.99731       1.50169       0.95937
    3           -3.24609      -1.57062       3.97780      -0.16671      -0.95173       0.19645       1.12744       5.10968       0.97922
    4            0.08826      -0.00032      -0.16671    1851.41857    1842.77634      -2.58266     -21.97807    -163.53637     -26.21676
    5            0.88220       0.52187      -0.95173    1842.77634    1834.38053      -2.49154     -21.82099    -163.24386     -26.03641
    6            0.26019       0.50452       0.19645      -2.58266      -2.49154       3.76810       9.07100      20.39137       8.70026
    7            0.12200       0.99731       1.12744     -21.97807     -21.82099       9.07100      37.11085      97.36823      31.06467
    8           -1.62747       1.50169       5.10968    -163.53637    -163.24386      20.39137      97.36823     834.80181      90.59780
    9            0.17326       0.95937       0.97922     -26.21676     -26.03641       8.70026      31.06467      90.59780      28.12504
#  ==========================================================================


#                    CORRELATION MATRIX

#    Layer             1             2             3             4             5             6             7             8             9
#  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1       1.000000e+00  8.799332e-01 -8.990588e-01  1.133104e-03  1.137808e-02  7.404066e-02  1.106228e-02 -3.111503e-02  1.804687e-02
    2       8.799332e-01  1.000000e+00 -5.831008e-01 -5.447399e-06  9.022221e-03  1.924460e-01  1.212197e-01  3.848413e-02  1.339465e-01
    3      -8.990588e-01 -5.831008e-01  1.000000e+00 -1.942591e-03 -1.114166e-02  5.074252e-02  9.279446e-02  8.867083e-02  9.257942e-02
    4       1.133104e-03 -5.447399e-06 -1.942591e-03  1.000000e+00  9.999438e-01 -3.092095e-02 -8.384687e-02 -1.315438e-01 -1.148894e-01
    5       1.137808e-02  9.022221e-03 -1.114166e-02  9.999438e-01  1.000000e+00 -2.996828e-02 -8.363330e-02 -1.319169e-01 -1.146278e-01
    6       7.404066e-02  1.924460e-01  5.074252e-02 -3.092095e-02 -2.996828e-02  1.000000e+00  7.670852e-01  3.635745e-01  8.451314e-01
    7       1.106228e-02  1.212197e-01  9.279446e-02 -8.384687e-02 -8.363330e-02  7.670852e-01  1.000000e+00  5.531910e-01  9.615450e-01
    8      -3.111503e-02  3.848413e-02  8.867083e-02 -1.315438e-01 -1.319169e-01  3.635745e-01  5.531910e-01  1.000000e+00  5.912612e-01
    9       1.804687e-02  1.339465e-01  9.257942e-02 -1.148894e-01 -1.146278e-01  8.451314e-01  9.615450e-01  5.912612e-01  1.000000e+00
#  ==========================================================================


#                 EIGENVALUES AND EIGENVECTORS

# Number of Input Layers     Number of Principal Component Layers
        9                              9
# PC Layer             1             2             3             4             5             6             7             8             9
#  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Eigenvalues
            3.705257e+03  8.381912e+02  4.377424e+01  8.084394e+00  1.883812e+00  9.943425e-01  4.918035e-01  6.622241e-03  1.738068e-09
# Eigenvectors
# Input Layer
    1       2.192873e-04 -1.818010e-03  1.345937e-02  6.317391e-01  8.809529e-03  1.984875e-01  3.261382e-02  7.579221e-02  7.446061e-01
    2       6.023640e-05  2.071264e-03  2.851663e-02  3.896804e-01  1.093371e-01  7.306676e-01  8.691365e-02  6.787337e-02 -5.379044e-01
    3      -3.311373e-04  6.243791e-03  1.345306e-02 -6.598040e-01  1.322039e-01  6.204574e-01  5.684231e-02 -5.041374e-02  3.952476e-01
    4       7.063134e-01  5.875462e-02 -5.947862e-04 -7.660754e-02 -1.822955e-03 -2.488124e-02  5.956246e-03  7.008155e-01 -3.591517e-08
    5       7.030655e-01  5.795434e-02  3.685297e-03  7.689155e-02  2.311806e-03  2.405423e-02 -3.063707e-03 -7.041455e-01  3.612876e-08
    6      -1.466764e-03  2.613170e-02  2.168027e-01  3.578683e-02  6.838701e-01 -4.833176e-02 -6.934907e-01  9.340320e-03 -3.199566e-09
    7      -1.067006e-02  1.208553e-01  7.369415e-01 -2.465658e-02 -5.656805e-01  1.077937e-01 -3.316046e-01  3.725644e-03  1.071423e-10
    8      -8.097890e-02  9.826090e-01 -1.664714e-01  6.585910e-03  1.983965e-03  1.415769e-03 -1.264850e-02 -2.374949e-05 -1.137243e-10
    9      -1.210278e-02  1.110556e-01  6.172615e-01  7.134783e-04  4.275565e-01 -1.631103e-01  6.301234e-01 -6.545261e-03  9.112758e-10
#  ==========================================================================

#                 PERCENT AND ACCUMULATIVE EIGENVALUES

# PC Layer   EigenValue   Percent of EigenValues   Accumulative of EigenValues
    1  3.705257e+03          80.5721               80.5721
    2  8.381912e+02          18.2268               98.7989
    3  4.377424e+01           0.9519               99.7508
    4  8.084394e+00           0.1758               99.9266
    5  1.883812e+00           0.0410               99.9675
    6  9.943425e-01           0.0216               99.9892
    7  4.918035e-01           0.0107               99.9999
    8  6.622241e-03           0.0001              100.0000
    9  1.738068e-09           0.0000              100.0000
#  ==========================================================================
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Python?

Comment: While I'm looking to accomplish this in R, the PCA was calculated in arc.py and I'm open to using python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot PCA loadings and loading in biplot in sklearn (like R's autoplot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216897/plot-pca-loadings-and-loading-in-biplot-in-sklearn-like-rs-autoplot)